# Rearrange tree using labels

Tags: algorithm, tree, tree-traversal

Consider a tree (unordered) in which the nodes are labelled 0 through n, with the root node always labelled 0.

I want to construct a separate tree, in which the parent of each non-root node m is its nearest ancestor with label less than m.

For example, given this tree:

[image: (0 (1 (3)) (5 (7 (9 4) 2 (6))) 8)]

the required output is:

[image: (0 (1 (3) 5 (7 (9))) 4 2 (6) 8)]

Notice that node 2 has a lesser label than its parent 5, so it moves up the tree; node 4 is less than its parent 7 and its grandparent 5 so it moves up the tree to its great-grandparent 0.

The naïve approach is to process each node independently, traversing upwards until we encounter a lower label. This becomes very expensive for situations such as:

[image: (0 (n (n-1 ... (2 (1)))))]

It feels like there should be a fairly straightforward sub-quadratic algorithm for processing such a rearrangement, but I can't formulate the right concoction or even find an obvious traversal order to minimise the amount of redundant processing. Is this a common problem with a well-defined solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm will be the following:

1. set 0 as the root of a tree
2. perform DFS on the original tree.
3. perform recursive inject.

recursive inject(node, parent):

1. if node larger than parent, inject as child of the parent.
2. otherwise recursive inject (node, parent.parent)

Comment: Ah yes that's the one! Straightforward, trivial to see that it works.
Easy to make an iterative version of the recursion too.
Thanks @xenteros.

Comment: @MorT there is no need to replace recursion with iterative algorithm. You can have the same performance and clearer code. btw, on [so] we upvote useful answers and additionaly accept the best one :)

Comment: Alas the problem as presented here is an extensively pruned edition of a larger system. The actual implementation does not offer any guarantees about tree depth, and the embedding does not lend itself to tail recursion.

Thanks for the tip about etiquette ;)